# 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' why try to debug existing project

Tags: asp.net

I have taken over a project from another developer.

It is an ASP.NET VB Web Project developed in Visual Studio 2010

I am working on the same machine that the previous developer used.

I have access to the previous developers account.

If I login as the previous developer and Go to File ->  Open Web Site… I can get the web site to debug and run.

If I copy the website to my user name and try to open the website I receive the following error:

```
“A first chance exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException'
occurred in System.Configuration.dll”
```

I have copied the original location the “websites” and “projects “ directories over and made them all relative to each other.

There are no build errors.

I can find no unresolved references.

Even if I try to open the original location in the previous developers directory under my user name I still get the error.

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Look at the full stack trace of the exception.  Find the application code in the stack trace and see what its trying to do.  Failing that, use ILSpy to disassemble the relevant assemblies and look at their code.

Comment: There is not a full stack trace. This error appears in the output window. It stops when I close the browser window. It keeps repeating the longer the broweser window is open. The Browser window remains blank.......

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark...

Copying the files may be preventing you from being able to write files to the bin folder in the application

Comment: I am sorry. What does that mean?